# How to send a multidimensional array with PHP cURL without array keys from the nested arrays?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

**Introduction**

So I'm trying to send form values as a query string to an API. The API expects a query string like this:

```
&name=Charles+Hansen&email=example@email.com&locations=23433&locations=23231&propertyTypes=APARTMENT&propertyTypes=TOWNHOUSE&message=test"
```

As you can see there are multiple "propertyTypes" and "locations" depending on how many property types or locations the user picks in the form. Because of that I have stored all $_POST data in a multidimensional array which looks like this, since I obviously can't have multiple keys with the same name "propertyTypes" or "locations":

```
Array
(
    [name] => Charles Hansen
    [email] => example@email.com
    [locations] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23433
            [1] => 23231
        )
    [propertyTypes] => Array
        (
            [0] => APARTMENT
            [1] => TOWNHOUSE
        )
    [message] => test
)
```

cURL does not support multidimensional arrays, therefore I first build the query myself before using it. This is my cURL function:

```
function sg_order($post_fields) {
    if($post_fields) {
        $query = http_build_query($post_fields);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/order?orgKey=' . constant('ORG_KEY'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                 
          'Content-Length: ' . strlen($query))
        );
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if(curl_errno($ch)) {
          error_log('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch) . $result);
        }else{
          error_log('Curl response: ' . $status);
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

`orgKey` is a required parameter for validation.

**The problem**

My problem is, that the query built by `$query = http_build_query($post_fields);` contains the keys for the nested arrays ([0], [1] etc.). The result of `$query` looks like this:

```
&name=Charles+Hansen&email=example@email.com&locations[0]=23433&locations[1]=23231&propertyTypes[0]=APARTMENT&propertyTypes[1]=TOWNHOUSE&message=test"
```

How do I get rid of the keys ([0], [1] etc.) so that the query looks exactly like what the API expects?

**Additional info**

- I have no control over the API
- I am not sending files, so a solution does not have to work with files

Comment: Conver it to json than try to send

Comment: @YasinPatel I could try that, but as far as I know their API only accepts a URL encoded string. If I send it as json, will it automatically be converted to an URL encoded string by curl, because of the HTTPHEADER setting?

Comment: If you don’t want to write your own version of http_build_query, then I’d suggest you modify https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#111819 by replacing the matches with an empty string instead of `'%5B%5D'`.

Comment: @04FS Yea, that works! Thanks! If you make an answer i'll accept that as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t want to write your own version of http_build_query, then I’d suggest you modify the version from this user comment in the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#111819

```
    $query = http_build_query($query);
    $query = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/simU', '%5B%5D', $query);
```

They are replacing `foo[xy]` with `foo[]` here - since you don’t want to keep the `[]` either, just replace `'%5B%5D'` in the preg_replace call with an empty string instead.

Comment: Thanks again. Bonus question: what does "simU" in that preg_replace mean?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php : PCRE_DOTALL (useless here IMHO), PCRE_CASELESS (useless here IMHO), PCRE_MULTILINE (useless here IMHO), PCRE_UNGREEDY (useless here IMHO). In other words, for this specific pattern, none of the modifiers is needed

Comment: @Piskvor thanks, I was typing a similar response in the meantime. The only one I can see _maybe_ making a bit of sense here is `i` - _if_ `http_build_query` were to erratically change its behavior one day, and return lower-case hex digits in the percent encoding of the square brackets, then `%5B` and `%5D` would still match - not sure how likely that is though. The rest of them were probably just added by whoever wrote this out of habit, I guess.

Comment: Would not match anyway, `[0-9]` is `[0123456789]`, AFAIK these don't have a lower/upper case ;) Looks like habit, sure: which is why I have qualified it "for this specific pattern."

Comment: @Piskvor I was referring to the curly brackets around the number - these are URL-encoded as `%5B` and `%5D` in the return value of `http_build_query`, and part of the pattern. Should `http_build_query` decide one day to return those as `%5b` and `%5d` instead (in terms of URL-encoding, both versions are allowed), then the pattern as-is would still work with the `i` modifier.

Comment: pattern modifiers `s` and `m` are absolutely useless/affectless on the written pattern.